# Since $uu^T=\langle u, u\rangle = \|u\|$, should this equal to $1$? How come $u^Tu=1?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

$$\|u\| = 1$$
let $\hat{X_j}$ be the projected vector correspond to the span of $u$, and that $\hat{X_j} = uu^TX_j$. 
The projection matrix $uu^T$ is

1) $(uu^T)^T = uu^T$.

2) $(uu^T)(uu^T) = uu^T$.

---

I have two questions.

**Q1 .**  Since $uu^T=\langle u, u\rangle = \|u\|$, should this equal to $1$?

**Q2 .** How come $u^Tu=1?$

Comment: Assuming $u$ is a column vector, $uu^\top$ is the outer product, not inner product. I think you've got $u$ and $u^\top$ mixed up.

Comment: yes, they are column vector.... I see now